# Float div's on left and right while keeping on separate lines

Tags: html, css, css-float

My code is provided below, and I am having 2 problems.

**Problem #1:** At the 2nd message you can see, that "Doe" was moved to new line instead resizing same line. 
**Problem #2:** I have each line floated and using `clear: both` in my `.t_message`, but, as you can see, two blocks are on the same line.

Why and how can i fix it? Thanks.

```css
.time {
    float: right;  
}

.t_message {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 17px;
    background: #e8e8f8;
    clear: both;
    margin: 13px 11px 0 11px;
}

.t_message .time {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-left : 20px;
}

.my_t_message {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

.my_t_message .avatar {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.my_t_message .time {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.name {
    display: block;
}

.b_message {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.t_message .avatar {
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.name {
    color: #369;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="talkTab">
    <div id="dialogInterface">
      
      <div class="t_message">
     <div class="b_message">
       <div class="time"> 
         23:61
       </div>
       <div class="name">
         John Doe
          </div>
          <div class="c_message">
            Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! 
    </div>
        </div>
   </div>
      
      <div class="t_message my_t_message">
     <div class="b_message">
       <div class="time"> 
         23:61
       </div>
       <div class="name">
         My Account
          </div>
          <div class="c_message">
            Hi, guys...
    </div>
        </div>
   </div>
      
      <div class="t_message">
     <div class="b_message">
       <div class="time"> 
         23:61
       </div>
       <div class="name">
         John Doe
          </div>
          <div class="c_message">
            It is message #2.
    </div>
        </div>
   </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced some of your code because I was not able to get it working with the existing. I believe this is what you are looking for. Main issue seemed to be replacing the `inline-block` on `t_message` to `float: left;`

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rpoptm9/)**

```css
    span {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .t_message {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 17px;
        background: #e8e8f8;
        margin: 13px 11px 0 11px;
        clear: both;
    }
    .t_message .time {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-left : 20px;
    }
    .my_t_message {
        float: right;  
    }
    .my_t_message .avatar {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .t_message .avatar {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }
    .name {
        color: #369;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .c_message {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .content {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
        <div id="talkTab">
            <div id="dialogInterface">
                <div class="t_message">
                   <div class="b_message">
                       <span class="name">John Doe</span>
                       <span class="time">23:61</span>
                       <div class="c_message">Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah!</div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="t_message my_t_message">
                    <div class="b_message"> 
                        <span class="name">My Account</span>
                        <span class="time">23:61</span>
                        <div class="c_message">Hi, guys...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="t_message"> 
                    <div class="b_message"> 
                        <span class="name">John Doe</span>
                        <span class="time">23:61</span>
                        <div class="c_message">It is message #2.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working on jsfiddle.. But when i copy that to my project it's not working :D Here is what i got: http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/14/1126/h_1416962888_1986445_d09278fdbd.png

Comment: I'm not able to view that image from my current location. But if it is not working in your environment more than likely a CSS inheritance issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the `name` class from wrapping by adding these styles:

```
.name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.time {
    float: right;  
}

.t_message {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 17px;
    background: #e8e8f8;
    clear: both;
    margin: 13px 11px 0 11px;
}

.t_message .time {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-left : 20px;
}

.my_t_message {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

.my_t_message .avatar {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.my_t_message .time {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.name {
    display: block;
}

.b_message {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.t_message .avatar {
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.name {
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="talkTab">
    <div id="dialogInterface">
      
      <div class="t_message">
     <div class="b_message">
       <div class="time"> 
         23:61
       </div>
       <div class="name">
         John Doe
          </div>
          <div class="c_message">
            Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! Blah blah blah! 
    </div>
        </div>
   </div>
      
      <div class="t_message my_t_message">
     <div class="b_message">
       <div class="time"> 
         23:61
       </div>
       <div class="name">
         My Account
          </div>
          <div class="c_message">
            Hi, guys...
    </div>
        </div>
   </div>
      
      <div class="t_message">
     <div class="b_message">
       <div class="time"> 
         23:61
       </div>
       <div class="name">
         John Doe
          </div>
          <div class="c_message">
            It is message #2.
    </div>
        </div>
   </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried that, but name in the right block is cut(t?)ed now.

Comment: Now try to replace "It is message #2" by just "+". Still not working, but thanks anyway!